# Error occurred while compiling CnosDB meta component in Docker environment

Tags: cnosdb

Run this command to build a docker image:

```
sudo docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile_meta .
```

Occurred error:

```
...
   Compiling datafusion-proto v22.0.0 (https://github.com/cnosdb/arrow-datafusion.git?branch=22.0.0#fb2cd91e)
   Compiling models v2.3.0 (/cnosdb/common/models)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
    --> common/models/src/meta_data.rs:350:26
     |
350  |             libc::statfs(c_storage_path.as_ptr() as *const i8, statfs.as_mut_ptr())
     |             ------------ expected `*const u8`, found `*const i8`
     |             |
     |             arguments to this function are incorrect
     |
     = note: expected raw pointer `*const u8`
                found raw pointer `*const i8`
note: function defined here
    --> /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/libc-0.2.142/src/unix/linux_like/mod.rs:1683:12
     |
1683 |     pub fn statfs(path: *const ::c_char, buf: *mut statfs) -> ::c_int;
     |            ^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `models` (lib) due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The command '/bin/sh -c cargo build --release --workspace --bin cnosdb-meta' returned a non-zero code: 101
```

When compiling meta separately, an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Modify as follows：

vim common/models/src/meta_data.rs

350 lines：

```
check_err(unsafe {
    libc::statfs(c_storage_path.as_ptr() as *const u8, statfs.as_mut_ptr())
})?;
```